# Displaying elements XSLT using concat

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to get something like that, but with all genres and movies not only the first one

`A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation
A Beautiful Mind    Animation`

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="films3.xsl"?>
<list>

            List:

        <movie cinema="yes">A Beautiful Mind</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Avatar</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Cast Away</movie>

        <movie cinema="no">Fight Club</movie>

        <movie cinema="no">Forest Gump</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Gladiator</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Inception</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Inglourious Basterds</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Intouchables</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Léon</movie>

        <movie cinema="no">Matrix</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Pulp Fiction</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Requiem for a Dream</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Saving Private Ryan</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Schindler's List</movie>

        <movie cinema="no">Se7en</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Seven Pounds</movie>

        <movie cinema="no">Shrek</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Shutter Island </movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Slumdog Millionaire</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Godfather</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Green Mile</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Hangover</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Pianist</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Shawshank Redemption</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Silence of the Lambs</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">The Sixth Sense</movie>

        <movie cinema="yes">Titanic </movie>



        Genres' list:

        <genre>Animation</genre>

            <genre>Biography</genre>

            <genre>Biography, drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>History</genre>

            <genre>War</genre>

            <genre>War</genre>

            <genre>War</genre>

            <genre>Fantasy</genre>

            <genre>Thriller</genre>

            <genre>Thriller</genre>

            <genre>Comedy</genre>

            <genre>Crime</genre>

            <genre>Crime</genre>

            <genre>Romance</genre>

            <genre>Adventure</genre>

            <genre>Sci-Fi</genre>

            <genre>Sci-Fi</genre>

            <genre>Drama</genre>

            <genre>Thriller</genre>

            <genre>Thriller</genre>

            <genre>Thriller</genre>

            <genre>War</genre>


    How many movies?: 30
</list>
```

And here is .xsl that I'm using to get .txt I want:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:variable name="movie">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="/list/movie" />
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="gen">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="/list/genre"/>
 </xsl:variable>



 <!--This one below is used only-->
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="/list/movie">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(/list/movie,'    ',/list/genre)"/>
  <xsl:text>
 </xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
 <!--><xsl:value-of select="concat($gen,'                 ',$movie)"/>-->

 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="/movie">
 <xsl:for-each select="movie">
  <xsl:value-of select="movie"/>
 <xsl:text>


  </xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are few solutions mentioned in code, every is working wrong, I'm trying to complete this since a few days, so finally I've decided to come here and ask for help. I just need some advices.

Comment: I don't see anything in your input XML that links a movie to a specific genre. At first, I thought each movie's genre would be at the corresponding position in the genres list, but `A Beautiful Mind` is not an animation film.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know, because these lists are alphabetical, they're not connected in a way that movie has his own genre, and thanks a lot, your answer solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment to your question, I don't see any connection between the movies and the genres other than a common count.

If you just want to list them side-by-side, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/list">
    <xsl:for-each select="movie">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../genre[$i]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```